# Backbone child view not removing correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have an OuterView, and a MainView which contains multiple ChildViews. For some event in OuterView, I'll close the current MainView (which kicks off a close function on each ChildView), and I'll re-render a new MainView with a different of ChildViews (there is nothing stopping a ChildView appearing on one MainView, then appearing on another - think of the changing of MainViews as a slightly different query/filter).

Whilst I'm viewing a MainView, some action/event can remove a single ChildView, calling its close function. It currently works like this:

1) If I have never seen that ChildView before (eg. just refreshed entire page, or changed MainView and seen ChildView for the same time), removing it works well

2) If I have seen that ChildView before (eg. in my OuterView I go to page 1 filter, then to page 2, then back to page 1), when the remove event is triggered on my ChildView, it doesn't remove the view/HTML, even though it goes through the close function.

My MainView close function looks like this:

```
            close: function() {
                for (var key in this.childViews) {
                    this.childViews[key].close();
                }

                this.undelegateEvents();
                this.$el.empty();
                this.stopListening();
                this.remove();
        },
```

My ChildView close function looks like this:

```
        close: function() {
            this.$el.empty();
            this.stopListening();         
            this.remove();
        }
```

Does anybody know why my ChildView isn't closing well if it has been seen before? (I am guessing it's not removed well the first time, so it would be an issue with closing the view).

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Please share a [mcve]

Comment: I've now found the issue, which was actually related to a variable on the prototype being used to track views, which was shared between instances of the ChildView.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know without seeing the rest of your code, but if no console errors are thrown, I would guess that your child view is not attached to the DOM element you think it is.

Within your ChildView close method, try adding in `console.log(this.$el[0])` after you empty it. If the logged `div` is empty, but your html is still on the page, then the view is likely using a detached `div`, not the on-page element you think it is.

When the DOM elements your views may be attached to are manipulated, you can use [setElement](http://backbonejs.org/#View-setElement) to make sure they are attached in the right place.